# How to retrieve the attribute of an element?

Tags: selenium

Hi I have a html code:

```
<img style="border-width:0px;" alt="graph" src="abc.ashx?meter=1203&amp;start=20131007000000&amp;end=20131028000000" id="ctl00_phBody_imgChart">
```

i want to retrieve the **start** and **end** parameters. I tried with the below code but did not work for me.

```
driver.findElement.id("ctl00_phBody_imgChart").getAttribut("start")
```

Please anyone help on the same.

Thanks,

Sudhansu

Comment: Please add example html code what you working on so help for you can be accurate.

Comment: wat error are u getting?....."e" is missing from "getAttribut",i guess that is a typo..

Comment: <img style="border-width:0px;" alt="graph" src="abc.ashx?meter=1203&amp;start=20131007000000&amp;end=20131028000000" id="ctl00_phBody_imgChart"> This is the code i am using

Comment: even the format for finding elements isn't right,it should be "driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_phBody_imgChart"))"....please edit ur question and rewrite the code which u have tried to compile..

Comment: sorry the format is: driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_phBody_imgChart")).getAttribute("start")); Is this sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Your **Start** and **End** are in attribute **src**, so you need to get src and get info that you need, thorugh regexp, try this **(Java Example)**:

```
String attribute = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_phBody_imgChart")).getAttribute("src");
//atribute = abc.ashx?meter=1203&amp;start=20131007000000&amp;end=20131028000000
String yourStart;
String yourEnd;

Pattern patternStart = Pattern.compile("(?<=start=)(.*?)(?=\;)");
Pattern patternEnd = Pattern.compile("(?<=end=)(.*?).*");

Matcher matcherStart = patternStart.matcher(attribute);
Matcher matcherEnd = patternEnd.matcher(attribute);

if (matcherStart.find()) {
      yourStart = matcherStart.group(1);
}
if (matcherEnd.find()) {
      yourEnd = matcherEnd.group(1);
}
```